# How does javascript call a newly added method after instantiation of the class/object occured?

Tags: javascript, oop

Please help me understand how this is happening...

How is it possible that after myObject is instantiated, that I can add new methods to my original class/object constructor and get both results...

I would expect I would have to instantiate mathX as myObject2 to get this to work...

```js
// make class/object with properties & methods
function mathX(num1, num2) {
    this.factor = 10;
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.multiplySum = function() {
        return (this.num1 + this.num2) * this.factor;
    }
}

// instantiate class/object with properties & methods
var myObject = new mathX(5, 5);

document.write("multiplySum result = " + myObject.multiplySum() + "<br>");

// add new method to class/object AFTER instantiation
mathX.prototype.sumAll = function() {
    return this.num1 + this.num2 + this.factor;
}

// immediately use new method on previously instantiated class/object
document.write("sumAll result = " + myObject.sumAll() + "<br>");

// how is this possible?  Shouldn't this fail?

// How does javasript call a newly added method after instantiation of the class/object occured?
```

Comment: Yes, because javascript use the same references for `object`. You need to create a deep copy if you don't want this.

Comment: myObject is a **reference** to a mathX object that your then changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because inheritance is "live".

When you create an object A which inherits from another object B, A does not locally store a copy of the properties of B at that time. Instead, it just references B in its [[Prototype]].

Then, when you attempt to access a property on A but there is no own property with that name, B will be consulted instead.

So when you alter an object, you are potentially impacting all objects which inherit from that one.

```js
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.foo); // undefined
Object.prototype.foo = "bar";
console.log(obj.foo); // "bar"
```

Comment: So in a way are you saying both Object A and Object B both exist...but there is a reference between them - even if they have the same name?   So in my example I have mathX.prototype.sumAll() as a new method being attached to the original object...is that stored somewhere as an improved-copy of the original mathx object?  Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: `sumAll` is stored as a property of `mathX.prototype`. It will potentially be available on all objects which inherit from `mathX.prototype`, even if they were created before.

Comment: I must have a definition problem as well.  I thought sumAll() was a method. But never the less I suppose I also did not understand the way javascript references objects 'live'  - my previous understand was they were somehow written to memory over and over again like documents.  I suppose this came from either learning PHP first...or perhaps just being a noob :-J

Comment: @n8thanael A function that is the value of a property is called "method". So `mathX.prototype.sumAll` is a method, yes.

Comment: Thanks.  I get lost in the terms as I'm new to this.  I thought maybe I had that wrong too - or perhaps since everything in JavaScript is an object vs. PHP I should have been referring to methods differently in JS.  I greatly appreciate your help, hopefully I can give something back to the community in the future.